# How to execute a Ruby system call in the context of the current shell

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm executing a call to `rvm use ...` from inside a Ruby script:

```
system "rvm use 2.5.5"
```

When the above executes, I get

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.  

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
```

I'm fairly sure that I'm logged in as a login shell.  There's no problem using normal RVM commands in the terminal I have open.  Does the `system` command pick up on the current shell or does it use something else by default?  If it uses something else, what's the best way to get Ruby to run a command in the context of the current shell?

Comment: Backtick notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things can be tricky with RVM. Try this:

```
"/bin/bash -c -l 'rvm use 2.5.5 && <add your system commands here>'"
```

Note: I guess it would create a *new* shell environment. Do you really need to access your *current* shell?

Comment: I only wanted to access the current shell because it was already a login shell.  This solution works great.